# gsutil rsync uploading then immediately deleting file, leaving source and target in different states

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a script which is running `gsutil rsync -r -d -c`, and occasionally it will leave the source and target directories out of sync. The last file in in the list (named version.json) is first uploaded, and then immediately deleted.

Has anybody encountered this bug?

Additional information:

- versioning is turned off in the target bucket
- This occurs when attempting to overwrite the entire contents of the target bucket, which is already present.

Comment: In general, source and target directories can get slightly out of sync because listing in Google Cloud Storage is eventually consistent.  But I would not expect your command to upload and then delete a file if that file always existed on the local filesystem.  Could you run your command with the debug (-D) flag and send the debug logs to gs-team@google.com?  Example: "gsutil -D rsync -r -d -c <your arguments>"

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will definitely follow up with the gs-team.